# Is there a way to declare computed properties on Interface?

Tags: java, groovy, jspresso

In my model, I declared an interface :

```
Interface('IMovement') {
    date_time 'etd'
    date_time 'rtd'
}
```

and I have a lot of entities extending this interface :

```
Entity('Entity1', extend:'IMovement') {
...
}
```

I would like to enhance the interface by adding a computed property which computes the difference between the dates : rtd-etd.

I added a computed property on the Interface and generated the extension.

```
public class IMovementExtension extends AbstractComponentExtension<IMovement> {

    public IMovementExtension(IMovement component) {
        super(component);

        //registerNotificationForwarding(component, IMovement.FIELD, IMovement.COMPUTED_FIELD);
    } ...
```

But the following error is raised by Eclipse :

> Bound mismatch: The type IMovement is not a valid substitute for the
>   bounded parameter  of the type
>   AbstractComponentExtension

Is there a way to declare computed properties on Interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use computed properties on Jspresso interfaces but you have to tell the framework that your interface implements (extends) `IComponent` so that you can use the extension mecanism.

This is easily achieved by using the services entry as demonstrated below :

```
Interface('IMovement',
  extension:'IMovementExtension',
  services:['org.jspresso.framework.model.component.IComponent':null]) {
    ...
}
```